# Door not closing properly

Tags: doors

[image: picture from inside the door][image: me putting washers behind lower hinge to help the problem]Winter is coming and I want to insulate my door frame so that cold air doesn’t leak in. That is when I noticed that the door is falling short of meeting the jam and is causing there to be a crack between the two , when the door is closed. I’m not too familiar wit explaining theses type of things so I took a few pictures to help out. I tried to fix the problem by putting some washers behind the lower hinge as you’ll see in the third picture. This worked sort of but not to the extent that i would like to see. I’ve also thought about just nailing another 1/2” piece of jam to the preexisting one to make sure it’s protruding far enough for the door and jam to meet and then still have enough room for a strip of weather tape. I’m open to any suggestions, I just wanted to let you know what ideas I had to begin with .[image: crack in door]

Comment: Something does not look right on the lock side of that door.  Can you post a picture of just that side of door frame with the door open?  On most doors that is the door stop and should extend past the closed door, but the inside seems too big.